# Azure DevOps Pipelines how to exclude tests with specified tag

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We use yaml pipelines to run our builds and unittests. We have some tests that require a deployed database, and we want to exclude those tests.
They are marked as follows:

```
   [TestCategory("DoNotRunOnBuild")]
   [TestClass]
   public class PersistencySqlServerTests
   {
     ...
   }
```

Our yaml looks like this:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'Run tests'
inputs:
  command: test
  projects: |
    **\*Test.csproj
    !**\*.IntegrationTest.csproj
    arguments: '--collect "Code coverage" --logger trx --results-directory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults/'
  testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=DoNotRunOnBuild'
  publishTestResults: false      
  testRunTitle: KooService
```

We copied this part "testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=DoNotRunOnBuild'" from a "classic" pipeline using the show as yaml feature, but it doesn't work, test are still run, and thus failing the build.

What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'Run tests'
inputs:
  command: test
  projects: |
    **\*.csproj
    !**\MeldingenComponentTests
    !**\*.IntegrationTest.csproj
  arguments: '--collect "Code coverage" --logger trx --filter "TestCategory!=DoNotRunOnBuild" --results-directory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults/'
  publishTestResults: false
  testRunTitle: KooService
```

It has to be part of the **arguments** in the form of a filter